# Saving a curl response into database

Tags: php, curl

I am getting this response

```
[{"id":15702671,"payment_id":15702666,"amount":20,"metadata":{},"source":{"id":"347862165","name":"Test Test","type":"collector"},"date_created":"2018-08-28T08:11:15.000-04:00","unique_sequence_number":null,"status":"approved"}]
```

This is my Code

```
$url = "https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/".$paymeny_id."/refunds?access_token=TEST-4015220099523401-082300-232be80199d9b1a9b0bac72d6af99fd2-347862165";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

how to save response value in variable ?

Comment: what do you mean by a variable, you already saving the response in `$output`

Comment: @RAUSHANKUMAR i know but response is not save in $output.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php explains what you need to do to get the actual result.

Comment: _"I am getting this response"_ - How do you determined that you get that response if `$output` doesn't contain it?

Comment: Well, the above question doesn't seem to be what the OP actually is asking about (reading the comments to the answers below) so I'm voting to close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$var = curl_exec($ch)
```

Hope this works!

to get the id

```
$var = json_decode($var);
$id = $var[0]->id;
```

Comment: How to get id value from response ?

Comment: @YennamPraveenkumar - That's not what you asked in your question? Is the question actually how to get the ID from the json response?

Comment: You need to pass `true` as the second argument to `json_decode()` or you'll get an object, not an array.

Comment: @Krishanu i m getting blank screen

Comment: @Magnus it should not. I have tried something like this in the past

Comment: Sorry about that :-)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option in your curl object to get the response using curl as

```
$url = "https://api.mercadopago.com/v1/payments/".$paymeny_id."/refunds?access_token=TEST-4015220099523401-082300-232be80199d9b1a9b0bac72d6af99fd2-347862165";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Well bro it must be true not $url in the retruntransfer. I made the same mistake :-)!!

Comment: @YennamPraveenkumar - Please add what you've tried to your question. It makes it easier for us to know what to suggest and not to suggest.